# My cat ate a (part of a) balloon. What should I do?

Tags: cats, eating

Yesterday I bought my cat a balloon thinking that she would be very pleased to play with it. But, as expected, my cat broke the balloon and when I checked up on her, a piece of it had disappeared.

I asked my vet if I should be concerned that she may have ate it and what I should do, and he told me that I should wait and observe if her behavior changed. So far I haven't noticed any strange behaviour.

I'm very worried and I want to know if the material of a balloon can be digested by a cat, and  if she can digest it easily.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Balloon material cannot be digested by cats. It may be able to pass through her digestive system, but it may also cause a blockage. A blockage is a VERY SERIOUS problem that requires IMMEDIATE vet attention.

Symptoms of a blockage can include:

- Vomiting
- Anorexia (not eating)
- Weakness/lethargy
- Diarrhea
- Weight loss

If your cat exhibits any of these signs, you should take her to the vet immediately.

In the future, do not allow your cat to play with balloons (or if you do, clip her claws beforehand and supervise her closely while she has access to the balloon).

Comment: I would note that if it passes through okay, you should be able to notice it in the cat's feces.

Comment: I had a kitten that used to love to eat rubber bands off the newspaper. Once I managed to pull it out when only a little was visible in the throat. She didn't like that and after that ran behind the oven to eat them in peace.  Eventually the bands came out in the poop like a little poo necklace. If the rubber part is small, things should be OK.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i'm very grateful. She vomitted again today and i took her immediatly to the vet. There an ultrasound was made on her belly, which revealed the part of the balloon somwhere near the duodenum. The vet decided it's not the time for surgery, and gave her some laxatives and drugs to help her digest the balloon. If the balloon won't get out untill this thursday, then my vet will open her. I hope it will be fine..